# my nginx regular expression routing is not working

Tags: regex, nginx

```
    location ~* "/mypath/([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]{12}$)" {
            return 301 https://new-domain.com;
    }
```

Above regular express is when user type `https://mywebsite.com/mypath/uy2hgy12jer2` in browser, it will be redirect to `https://new-domain.com`. But problem is when they type `https://mywebsite.com/mypath/uy2hgy12jer2?params=1287612`, it's also redirected. What I want is I want to make redirect only to `https://mywebsite.com/mypath/uy2hgy12jer2`. Please let me know how to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Location blocks in NGINX will only match the URI part but not the query string.

Alternatively, you can use below inside location block.

```
if ($is_args) {
    break;
}
```

I found this behavior after few trails in https://nginx.viraptor.info/. Any character you type after 12th character doesn't get matched except when it is a query string. Next I found the alternative I mentioned and the link below.

For more info - https://serverfault.com/questions/237517/nginx-query-keyword-matching-in-location